# How to make multilanguage views (Views-module)

Tags: drupal-6

I've been building a website with a whole bunch of articles in Dutch and English. But now I want to make a nice list of it according to their language.

I can fill in the path to a page (in the views-module) to nl/article_list but it doesn't follow that link when I click the Dutch translation which goes to nl/article_list. It doesn't show me any Dutch articles. Only English ones pop up here... :(

Can anyone say how to make this work with the language switcher?

Comment: Oh, I've found the answer myself.

So for anyone who needs an answer on the same subject:
http://www.computerminds.co.uk/multilingual-views-drupal-when-using-i18n-module
This is very useful in this position.

Comment: Rather than leave the answer buried in a comment, you should do a proper answer, then when the [minimum time delay has passed for self-answering](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) you can then mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I've found the answer myself. So for anyone who needs an answer on the same subject: http://www.computerminds.co.uk/multilingual-views-drupal-when-using-i18n-module

This is very useful in this position.